# Centre dot in probability notation?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

What does the dot mean in probability notation

I sometimes see things like $x \sim P_t(\centerdot \vert x, \theta_{db})$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this notation mean? $P(\cdot)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942419/what-does-this-notation-mean-p-cdot)

Comment: Note: I recommend keeping both questions, the linked question / dupe target has more detailed answers and is more general, but this question is nice because it spells it out as "Centre dot" which makes it easier for Google to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dot, $\cdot$, in this context is a placeholder for an event or random variable.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Zaz I found this post with more elaboration: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942419/what-does-this-notation-mean-p-cdot